# JPA OneToMany relation not automatically populated?

Tags: jpa, entity, one-to-many, populate, relation

I have a simple OneToMany relation between Task and TaskError.

Task maps the TaskErrors:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "task", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TaskError> taskErrorCollection;
```

The TaskErrors should be deleted when the Task is deleted, hence the orphanRemoval.

TaskError is connected to a Task:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Task task;
```

The List of TaskErrors in Task is not updated when I add a TaskError with this code:

```
TaskError taskError;
// set all taskErrors vars
taskErrorDAO.create(taskError);
```

So the database contains a row for the TaskError, while the List of TaskErrors in Task is not populated. Obviously, when I delete the Task, it gives a error:
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row

Am I personally required to populate the TaskError list in Task? Is there a way to have this List automatically be populated? A em.flush after taskErrorDAO.create(taskError) doesn't help.

[image: relation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer is responsible for in-memory representation of your entity relationships. So - yes, you are required to populate the `TaskError` instance in `Task` `TaskError`'s list.

You can try cleaning up your `PersistenceContext` cache for `Task` and re-fetching it directly from the database, so something like:

```
em.refresh(task);
```

or

```
em.clear();
task = em.find(Task.class, yourTaskId);
```

Either way, your JPA provider should clear the in-memory representation of your Entity, hit the database (which, as you've said, has correctly inserted row) to fetch it and load the list properly. However, I wouldn't go this way in a long-term perspective but just update my objects references accordingly.
If you refuse to update in-memory relationships of your entities, than you cannot use caching features of `PersistenceContext`. In order to have correct data you will need to hit the database every time you want to use/fetch your `Task` entity after any new `TaskError` has been assigned to it.

One more thing - why do you have `Cascade.ALL` in `TaskError`? Do you want to remove `Task` instance if `TaskError` is removed?

You can also check [this resource](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side) for more information.

Comment: Could you eleborate on " However, I wouldn't go this way in a long-term perspective but just update my objects references accordingly." Cascade.ALL in TaskError is not correct, but i'm not sure which other setting I should use. Task should not be deleted when a TaskError is deleted.

Comment: I've updated my answer as you requested. Hope it's clearer now. If this `Cascade.ALL` was added because you wished the `TaskError` to be propagated to the `Task` it was assigned to, than it won't work. The JPA states clearly, that its your responsibility to manage in-memory relationships.

Comment: My application uses 50 tables with around 30 relations. So updating all relations myself will be enormous and error prone. You say a solution would be to  hit the database every time you want to use/fetch your Task entity. Which I could with em.refresh(task)?

Comment: The idea is to force JPA provider to clear its cache and refresh the entity which is a 'one' part in `@OneToMany` relationship. Then its list should be properly initialized.

Comment: I've added link to my answer which might be interesting for you

Comment: Thx for the link. I smiled at this quote: "Some expect the JPA provider to have magic that automatically maintains relationships." :) Though one question: do I also have to update the relation when I edit a variable in Task or TaskError? For example if I do task.setStatus("a"), I assume the task reference in TaskError is not automagicly updated. Is it necessary to attach the task reference (task = em.merge(task)) before using it so that I use the updated task object?

Comment: If you update `TaskError`, the adequate entity in `Task` list should be also updated - they share the same reference (we're operating here on object's world, so in-memory representation of the DB.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5292/discussion-between-bigj-and-piotr-nowicki)